# How magnetic field loops are formed in TEM mode propagation?

Tags: electromagnetism

Magnetic fields always form a loop but usually in the pictures of TEM wave propagation, we see magnetic field lines as perpendicular to electric field lines like in the picture. How are the magnetic field loops are formed in TEM modes?
[image: TEM propagation]

Comment: Field lines may start and end at infinity and then are closed only at "infinity". There is also a TEM wave propagating in a coaxial cable and there the magnetic field lines are concentric circles around the inner wire.

Comment: Thank you so much!